# Saraswati mantra for recitation and need for guru

Tags: mantras, saraswati, initiation, meaning

What is the meaning of the following mantra?

> (om) वद वद वाग्वादिनी स्वाहा ।

Does this Saraswati mantra need a guru's initiation to recite (without om)?

Comment: Being endowed with pranava & Svaha, those who don't have yagnopavitam are prohibited from reciting this mantra. Being a Tantrika mantra, it is mandatory to undergo diksha in atleast in one Shakti mantra in order to perform its japa.